# RadListView - "load more items" is always visible with IncrementalLoadingMode="Explicit"

Tags: uwp, telerik

Using RadListView from Telerik with IncrementalLoadingMode="Explicit", but then the "load more items" button is always visible, even when there are no items in the listview instance.

Is there any way to hide the "load more items" button when there are no items? Makes no sense to have the button there when there are no items

Answer (score 0):

The "load more items" is actually the [`DataGridLoadDataControl`](https://github.com/telerik/UI-For-UWP/blob/e82d19046ba79e98e7699e7b5a280f9f2b0249c7/Controls/Grid/Grid.UWP/View/Controls/Loading/DataGridLoadDataControl.cs) in Telerik, you could try to find it in the UI visual tree by [`VisualTreeHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper), and then set it to invisible. For example (grid is the name of `RadDataGrid` control):

```
private void btnloadcompleted_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    IEnumerable<DataGridLoadDataControl> items = FindVisualChildren<DataGridLoadDataControl>(grid);
    foreach (DataGridLoadDataControl item in items)
    {
        item.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; 
    }
}
private static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn't really do anything, no visual change. I casted the sender parameter to a DependencyObject, which seems to be the correct object (the RadListView)

Comment: @SteinJ.Gran, please check it carefully: "grid is the name of RadDataGrid control", I just direct get the `RadDataGrid` object.If you tested that it do worked since I have tested it on my side.